# Is there any way to convert MULTI-Paged Tiff file which is in NDVI format to a normal RGB image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am am loading some images taken from dron in NDVI format, they are in TIFF format and for pages stick together, I wrote this code the unlayer the pages of TIFF files:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def unlayer(image,mode=True):
    im_list = []
    for i in range(0,image.n_frames):
        image.seek(i)
        if mode:
            im_list.append(np.array(image))
        else:
            im_list.append(image)
    return im_list

    
layered = unlayer(image,mode=True)
```

is there any way to convert them into a normal colored RGB format?
since the image is more than 2MB I upload it here if you can check:
https://easyupload.io/y05f4v

Generally, the four images in that TIFF file look like this:
I want to make a normal RGB out of it or them.

[image]

Comment: do you know the brand and model of camera? did you google that info to learn the specifications and perhaps spectral response of each layer? -- your plots should use a grayscale colormap. false color is just visually misleading. -- I can tell you that the TIFF doesn't contain a blue channel so you will not be able to reconstruct a "proper" visible light picture

Comment: here's a composite (with aligned layers) where I used B = 0.6*G to fill in the unavailable color: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjVCL.jpg